# need to remove <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"> from output in using <xsl:output method="text> xslt mediator

Tags: json, xslt, wso2, wso2-api-manager, xsl-output

I am using xslt mediator in wso2 studio developer.I add below code as local entity (add resource) in wso2 carbon->conf and use it in my xslt mediator as "key". I have list of objects in output in json format. because even I need list of one object so I use this mediator instead of foreach mediator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Asa.Mbdp.Platform.Publish.Tmc.Head.Proxy" 
        xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/">   
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" media-type="application/json"  method="text"/> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        {
        "Response":{
            "LivePrices":[
            <xsl:for-each select="s:Envelope/s:Body/t:LivePricesResponse/t:LivePricesResult/a:Close">
            {
            "Last":"<xsl:value-of select="a:Last"/>" , 
            "Price":"<xsl:value-of select="a:Price"/>",
            "Quantity":"<xsl:value-of select="a:Quantity"/>",
            "Since":"<xsl:value-of select="a:Since"/>"
            }
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>             
            ]
        }
    }
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my response start with text tag that I do not want to have it in my response. how can I remove this text tag.

```
<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">
        {
        "Response":{
            "LivePrices":[

            {
            "Last":"1880" , 
            "Price":"1851",
            "Quantity":"0",
            "Since":"2018-07-26T00:00:00"
            }

            ]
        }
    }
    </text>
```

I want this response:

```
{
        "Response":{
            "LivePrices":[

            {
            "Last":"1880" , 
            "Price":"1851",
            "Quantity":"0",
            "Since":"2018-07-26T00:00:00"
            }

            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using XSLT place the below code in your sequence

```
 <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>$1</format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body//*" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
<respond/>
```

This should give you the expected output